# Flash wmode="direct" issue on FB canvas app

Tags: facebook, flash, wmode

I develop a FB app using Flash using wmode="direct" (for 3D graphics).

In Internet Explorer, every time I popup any FB dialog (e.g Purchase Credits dialog), the flash disappears and when the dialog is closed, the flash does not re-appear...

I tried to set the visibility after dialog is closed:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/ (under "Special Considerations for Adobe Flash developers"), but it didn't work.

I've also tried the use FB.Init hideFlashCallback: 
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/555/ (under "Detecting visibility of Flash objects in Canvas apps"), but it doesn't seem to call the callback function...

Any one had the same issue and manage to make it work?
Any other suggestions?

P.S - I use swfobject to embed the SWF file.

Thank a lot!
Roei

---

UPDATE: I removed the appId param from the FB JS url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=XXXX&xfbml=1"></script>
```

and now the hideFlashCallback is executed, but still - the flash does not re-appear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the section [Special Considerations for Adobe Flash developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#flash) because the code snippet was a bit out-of-date.

The new snippet should give you an idea of how to use the hideFlashCallback, whose semantics have changed since that now out-of-date blog post, in that the function now takes a flash element as an argument.  (Unfortunately, we haven't redocumented it yet, but will soon).  One thing to note is that the callback does not currently work on IE8, but will after a fix gets pushed next Tuesday.

That said, it should work without that callback.  It may be caused by a javascript fatal that stops script execution before the re-showing happens.  Look in your javascript console to see if you see any errors.

Otherwise, if you can give me the canvas URL for your application, I can look into it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! It still doesn't work, so just to make sure before the next step, I should put all the code in a function and set it as a "hideFlashCallback" on FB.init?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the IE fix will be pushed Wednesday rather than Tuesday, due to the holiday schedule.

Comment: @Drew : I'm having the exact issue as Roei with 'direct' mode the function is never called. I checked the errors. The only errors I have are the domain issues on chrome which according to the docs can be ignored. Any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with other wmodes? what you can try is actually remove the div where you write your flash to, add it with innerHTML and run the swfobject.embed again

Comment: I must use "direct" in order to run my flash app.

Comment: If I'll run the swfobject.embed again, it will re-run the flash from the beginning, so it won't do the same as re-show it.